# How to extract 4 characters after '-' in a hostname

Tags: python

I have hostname of format `xxxxxxxx-abcdxxxxx` the `x` is not a set number so can't use print `text[10:14]` because I don't have a set location, the only pattern is 4 chars after `-`.

Comment: Split on dash, get the first 4 chars of the second split

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your first string is

```
s = "xxxxxxxx-abcdxxxxxxxxx"
```

you just do:

```
s.split("-",1)[1][:4]
```

which splits `s` into two strings in an array, `['xxxxxxxx','abcdxxxxxxxxx']` and  you get the result by taking the splicing of the 2nd array from index `0` to `4`.

```
abcd
```

Comment: thx have to wait 8 mins to accept your answer. text.split("-")[1][0:4]

Comment: I think OP wanted abcd, not the other chars

Comment: Your `[4:]` is going to return the `ssometiff` portion after the `abcd`

Comment: Yeah, true. Going  to fix...

Comment: How do i check if it isalpha on the result string ?

Comment: @Victor I updated my answer for `isalpha`

Comment: @m_callens thanks +1

Answer (score 5):

***Option 1***

Get the index of the dash and select from `+1` to `+5`:

```
a = 'xxxxxxx-abcdxxxxxxx'
i = a.index('-')
print(i[i+1:i+5])
```

***Option 2***

Use the `split` function and then get the first 4 values of the second element.

```
a = 'xxxxxxx-abcdxxxxxx'
print(a.split('-')[1][:4])
```

---

To see if a string is alphabetic, simply call the `isalpha` function:

```
str.isalpha()
```

It will return true or false based on result.